# Ruby Enumerator-based lazy flatten method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, enumerator

Michael Harrison has a great post on [lazy enumerators in Ruby](http://www.michaelharrison.ws/weblog/?p=163), providing an implementation of `lazy_select` and `lazy_map`. I am wondering whether the following implementation of `lazy_flatten` should have special processing for anything other than `Enumerator` and `Enumerable` types.

```
class Enumerator

  def lazy_flatten
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      self.each do |value|
        if value.kind_of? Enumerator
          value.lazy_flatten.each do |v|
            yielder.yield v
          end
        elsif value.kind_of? Enumerable
          value.flatten.each do |v|
            yielder.yield v
          end
        else
          yielder.yield value
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This doesn't seem lazy to me, as you are still performing old (non-lazy) `flatten` beneath.
2. `Enumerator` is `Enumerable`, so I think you don't need to handle it separately.
3. I would expect `lazy_flatten` to be method on `Enumerable`.

Here's how I would implement it:

```
module Enumerable
  def lazy_flatten
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      each do |element|
        if element.is_a? Enumerable
          element.lazy_flatten.each do |e|
            yielder.yield(e)
          end
        else
          yielder.yield(element)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Ruby 2.0+, you don't need to do this, you can just use [`Enumerable#lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-lazy), which returns an [`Enumerator::Lazy`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html).

For reasons that aren't clear to me, `Lazy` doesn't have `flatten`, but it has [`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-flat_map), so in principle you could just use `flat_map` with the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function).

```rb
module Enumerable
  def lazy_flatten
    self.lazy.flat_map { |x| x }
  end
end
```

`Lazy#flat_map` **mostly** takes care of decomposing any decomposable elements, but not quite -- from the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-flat_map):

> A value *x* returned by block is decomposed if either of the following conditions is true:
>
> 1. *x* responds to both `each` and `force`, which means that `x` is a lazy enumerator.
> 2. *x* is an array or responds to `to_ary`.

Note that `to_ary` is not a method on `Enumerable`, presumably to discourage [implicit conversions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/implicit_conversion_rdoc.html) from infinite sequences to arrays. This means, for instance, that if you try to `lazy_flatten` something that contains a `Set` or a `Range` with the above code, it (arguaby, see below) won't work:

```rb
a = [[1, 2, 3], Set[4, 5], 6, 7..8]
# => [[1, 2, 3], #<Set: {4, 5}>, 6, 7..8] 
f = a.lazy_flatten
# => #<Enumerator::Lazy: #<Enumerator::Lazy: [[1, 2, 3], #<Set: {4, 5}>, 6, 7..8]>:flat_map>  
f.to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, #<Set: {4, 5}>, 6, 7..8]
```

However, this is the same as the behavior of `Array#flatten`:

```rb
a.flatten
# => [1, 2, 3, #<Set: {4, 5}>, 6, 7..8]
```

(Although `Array#flatten` will not detect and decompose lazy enumerators, and `Lazy#flat_map` will.)

Whereas the OP's code or the code in [Mladen Jablanović's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073012/27358) will decompose the `Set` and the `Range`:

```rb
f = a.lazy_flatten # (M.J.'s code)
# => #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007fd819c166c0>:each>
f.to_a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

That code, however, will also iterate infinitely if passed something that includes an infinite sequence:

```rb
a = [[1, 2, 3], Set[4, 5], 6, 7..8, 9..Float::INFINITY]
# => [[1, 2, 3], #<Set: {4, 5}>, 6, 7..8, 9..Infinity]
f = a.lazy_flatten # (M.J.'s code)
# => #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007fd819a73d18>:each>
f.to_a
# => spins at 100% CPU for a while and eventually runs out of memory
```

If you consider that a feature, rather than a bug, one approach would be to modify the `flat_map`-based implementation to convert any enumerables it finds to lazy ones:

```rb
module Enumerable
  def lazy_flatten
    self.lazy.flat_map do |x|
      x.respond_to?(:lazy) ? x.lazy : x
    end
  end
end
```

This works even for nested lazy enumerables, as `Lazy#lazy` is smart enough to return itself.

Comment: For identity function, you can use `&:itself` :)